# Rails + Postgres fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Hi I'm trying to hook up postgresql to my rails project. I'm learning testing but my tests aren't running because of a postgresql error about having an incorrect password:

```
Edmunds-MacBook-Pro:langexchange edmundmai$ rake test:units
rake aborted!
fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I've already read around and my pg_hba.conf file was originally already like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     edmundmai
```

here's my database.yml file in my rails project

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: edmundmai
  password: 

development:
  <<: *default
  database: project_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: project_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: project_production
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this? We can chat if it's easier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you should change:

```
local   all             all                                     trust
```

to:

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

Then, You should create a **super_user** in PostgreSQL with `username` and `password`,after that adding `username` and `password` of new user to your `database.yml` file.

To create new `super_user`, open `Pg Admin III` and right click at the bottom `Login Roles` to create new super user.

Comment: hey kien. where do I find Pg Admin III? I've never heard of that before can you teach me how

Comment: Did you install PostgreSQL? After you installed it, you will have that tool. Search in your apps.

Comment: yeh I used homebrew to install postgres. Where exactly do I find Pg Admin III?

Comment: I think I found it. It's a program in my computer right? But I don't see the login roles buttons you're talking about.

Comment: yes, it's in your computer. Double click on local (localhost) server and scroll to the bottom, you will see it.

Comment: I think the issue is that I don't have any local servers... But when I try to create one with a name, username, password, it always gives me the error: `Error connecting to the server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "whatever_username_i_entered"`

Comment: try create a server with: Name: local, host: localhost, port: 5432, MaintenanceDB: postgres, username: postgres

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20524/discussion-between-kien-thanh-and-edmund)

Comment: Where do we have to change 'local   all             all                                     md5' ?

Answer (score 22):

Be sure that you have defined both RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV on your production hosting server.  I had a similar issue crop up where everything worked except `rake` and the solution was to add RACK_ENV=production to my environment.  RAILS_ENV was already set to production.

`export RACK_ENV=production`

`bundle exec rake db:version`

You should see some output such as:

`Current version: 20121126151935`

Solution:  make sure your Rails app has access to the RAILS_ENV and RACK_ENV environmental variables.  Also, ensure they're both the same value.

Comment: Thanks! Just switched from capistrano to another deployment solution. Apparently, capistrano takes care of RACK_ENV and RAILS_ENV in the background. I suppose I would've learned more without all the magic. :D

Comment: @Edmund, It would be great to make this the accepted answer.  It has more upvotes than the answer above :)

Comment: export RACK_ENV=production worked for me, however I'm using Passenger with Apache and according to the documentation Passenger is already setting RACK_ENV=production? This is my integration testing machine so I don't want to set a global RACK_ENV, feels like I'm missing somthing.

Answer (score 4):

On your local machine under the `test` and `development` sections of the `database.yml` file you should change the `username` to your logged in username. The rails generator makes it the same as your appname and that will not work. The `production` section will depend on your production setup. If you use heroku you do not need to change anything there.

Answer (score 0):

You need only to create the user/passw and schema(db) in postgres with pgadmin and put user/passw in database.yml. When I tryed to create database with rake db:create in current rails project folder, it failed, and trowed to me error could't create for postgreSQL adapter. After that I created the schema for rails project with pgadmin, everyrthing is fine without any changes in pg_hba.conf.