# PostgreSQL Ruby on Rails 5 on Windows - fe_sendauth: no password supplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am following [this guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5) to set up a rails project with Postgres.

So far I have installed postgress and the Heroku toolbelt and done the following:

1. Logged in using my heroku credentials
2. Created a rails project using postgres `rails new myapp --database=postgresq`
3. The default database.yml file looks like this:

   ```
   default: &default
     adapter: postgresql
     encoding: unicode
     pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

   development:
     <<: *default
     database: myapp_development

   test:
     <<: *default
     database: myapp_test

   production:
     <<: *default
     database: myapp_production
     username: myapp
     password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
   ```
4. created controller for homepage `rails g controller welcome`
5. Created index.html.erb and added routing. `root 'welcome#index'`

Then When I run the server, go to localhost:3000 and get the following error
`PG::ConnectionBad (fe_sendauth: no password supplied`):

Is the issue with the database.yml file or with the installation and setup of postgres?

Comment: Seems like this `<%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>` is `nil`. Are you sure you have the *EVN variables* in Heroku?

Comment: @pavan I don't think so, I will look into it. Thanks for the comment

Comment: I think it's issue with postgres config. Check out my answer for this question to solve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13690162/rails-postgres-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied/13690394#13690394

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. All I had to to was open pgAdmin and login using the password I created during installation.

Answer (score 2):

In config/database.yml, under default: &default, add:

```
 host: localhost
 username: postgres
 password: (the password you created during postgresql installation goes here)
 port: 5432
```

Then in your terminator run `rake db:create:all`(don't worry if you encountered the same problem here) and then run `rake db:migrate`, restart your rails server and your app should now work.

P.S. I've noticed that this question was asked over a year ago and that you already figured out a solution back then. But I am putting this solution here for anyone who might face the same problem because I encountered this problem two days ago and it took me some time to figure out a solution that worked for me.

Comment: This solution worked. Any pointers as to why setting these are important? I recently moved to a Windows platform. Had a hard time configuring a project clone. The project was setup in ubuntu. Found no issues there.

Comment: @arjun I am glad it worked for you, too. But to be honest, I don't know why setting these are important. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Add username and password to default

```
default: &default
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
      # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
      pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
      username: postgres
      password: postgres
```